# How to resample data in python

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, resampling

I have some data saved at a mean frequency of 47.4 Hz, and I want to resample them to 200 Hz. 
How can I do ? 
My data are like : [time, value] and the time is the time elapsed since the launch, in ms.
I know there is a resample function in pandas but how can I manage the Hz ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please share a sample of your data not as an image, and what you have tried so far

Comment: Here are my data (first the time, then the value) :

[[0,2092][10010,21][19989,2103][30030,2111][40039,2116]]

I've tried to use the resample() function of pandas but it's only working if you want to resample according to a time I think (like every 3s); I want to resample according to a Hertz frequency